# I want to set flex-direction property to Material UI Grid tag

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to set *direction* property to <Grid container> component of the Material UI framework. I have read the [doc](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/)
and **I tried setting direction property as column** like below:

```
<Grid container direction="column">
    <Grid item xs={12} >
        <h3 className="center-align">Log In</h3>
        <input type="text" id="user-email-on-login" placeholder="username@email.com" />
        <input type="password" id="user-password-on-login" placeholder="password" /> 
        <button>Log In</button>
    </Grid>

    <Grid item xs={12}>
        <button>Forgot Id/Password</button>
        <button>Create Account</button>
        <button>Remember Me</button>    
    </Grid>         
</Grid>
```

But the output is not expected result. The output seems the same with the way I have used *direction="row"*.
When I remove <Grid item> tag, then *direction=column* property on <Grid container> works perfectly.

If I have to use <Grid item> tag, is there a way to set *flex-direction* property as *column*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the "container" property to the grid element and thus have the "direction" property.

It's possible for an item to be both container and item at the same time.

Anyway, if you want to be more precise, you can upload an example of sandbox :)

Here's an example of what you want:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2m3blz

Comment: Thank you I solved this problem. And can I ask a question, how did you find the way mixing those of grid item tag and grid container tag ? I mean, I want to get the link

Comment: Well, I found a sample code in the Material-Ui documents, right here: https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/#complex-grid

I hope you've been helped :)